# Most Efficient Websocket Ping Interval on Mobile Devices

Tags: android, ios, mobile, websocket, energy

My aim is to minimize the battery/energy cost of maintaining a long-lived Websocket connection on an iPhone (but this applies to any mobile device), by allowing the cellular/wifi radios in the device to be powered down for as often/long as possible, while by finding the minimum ping frequency that still maintains the connection integrity.

Ignoring for a moment the fact that the "ping" lets us know whether the application on the server is alive or dead...

If TCP keepalive has a default 2 hour window, does this imply that "The Internet" won't kill our Websocket connection for some comparable period of time?

In the case even 30 second pings are pretty resource wasteful.

Does anyone have experience with tuning the pings to minimum frequency?

Comment: What framework are you using? Socket.IO runs ping/pongs by default, so these concerns are basically already handled for you. Also: You may be interested to know that "the internet" does not know or care that you have a connection. Notwithstanding a few technicalities, the only things that even "know" you have a connection are the two peers.

Comment: @greeble31 I'm using a C++ server framework. the ping frequency is definitely a concern bc it's the difference between the radio chip in the phone being able to power down for many minutes at a time... or being woken up every few seconds. That's where all of the energy overhead exists in maintaining the connection.

Comment: @greeble31 there are lots of concerns with NATs. Which can only maintain a certain volume of connections and after some time will evict the oldest and least used, that's the point of TCP KeepAlive. And (I assume) this is especially at play with cellular networks.. though would love some insight.